# How do I catch a Wharf Roach?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I know they're at the beach and they are there all year and all season long. But I can't find one by the beach. Any clues of how to catch it? Net? Fishing rod? Shadow size in water if the fishing rod is needed?

*EDIT*

Thank you so much! I was able to get two of them one for a neighbor and the other for the museum! :D

Comment: I'm still on Day 1 for my game anyway of tips for the two beaches on your town?

Comment: If you found the answer satisfactory, you can click on the checkmark on the left of the answer under the voting arrows and mark it as "Accepted". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to be quick! You may have to run after them a little to get close enough because they tend to zigzag around a lot. I caught one successfully using my net.

They skitter quite fast when you approach them, so I would recommend holding down <kbd>A</kbd> so you walk slower and hold your net ready to make it easier to catch them with it once they've paused. You'll swipe your net when you release <kbd>A</kbd> then.

You'll find them along the shoreline, and they're quite hard to miss noticing because they dart around a lot. You can also often find them on Tortimer's Island.

This is what they look like running around:

[image: WharfRoach1]

And when you catch them:

[image: WharfRoach2]

Note that if you miss them with your net when you try to catch them, they'll dive into the ground and disappear. You'll then have to wait for another to show up.

Comment: They're much more abundant and easier to catch on the island in my experience